# Filter and find integers in a String with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this long string:

```
String responseData = "fker.phone.bash,0,0,0"
    + "fker.phone.bash,0,0,0"
    + "fker.phone.bash,2,0,0";
```

What I want to do is to extract the integers in this string. I have successfully done that with this code:

```
 String pattern = "(\\d+)";
 // this pattern finds EVERY integer. I only want the integers after       the comma

        Pattern pr = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher match = pr.matcher(responseData);


        while (match.find()) {

            System.out.println(match.group());

        }
```

So far it is working, but I want to make my regex more secure because the responsedata I get is dynamic. Sometimes I might get an integer in the middle of the string, but I only want the last integers, meaning after the comma.

I know the regex for starts with is ^ and I have to put my comma tecken as an argument, but I don't know how to piece it all together and that is why I am asking for help. Thank you.

Comment: "*meaning after the comma*" there are many ways to do this. Have you tried simply placing comma before number and getting only numeric part? I mean something like `,(\d+)` and using `group(1)`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, I did try it. The problem was that I did not know how to filtrate the commas. I only wanted the pure numbers. :)

Comment: Do you know about [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in regex?

Answer (score 2):

```
String pattern = "(,)(\\d)+";
```

Then get the second group.

Comment: or use lookbehind `(?<=,)\\d+` and get the whole match

Answer (score 2):

You can use [positive lookbehind](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/regex/simple-positive-lookbehind/) for that:

```
String pattern = "(?<=,)\\d+";
```

You don't need to extract any groups to do use that solution, because lookbehind is [zero-length assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I think this is the cleanest approach, so you don't have to process any matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following and find by `match.group(1)`:

```
String pattern = ",(\\d+)";
```

See [working demo](http://ideone.com/PgiX0n)

You can also use word boundaries to get independent numbers:

```
String pattern = "\\b(\\d+)\\b";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this match the comma AND the following integer? I believe the OP is asking for just the integers.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I can filtrate the comma? I only want the pure numbers. Thank you again.